# Digest Retrive error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Password Digest to store password in Ruby on Rails sample app ( tutorial by Micheal Hartl).

```
validates(:name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 })
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates(:email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false })
has_secure_password
before_save { email.downcase! }
before_create :create_remember_token
validates(:password, length: { minimum: 6 })

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.digest( User.new_remember_token)
  end
```

now in my app after account creation i forgot my pass.
I open Db with SQlite database browser here password digest show 16 bit code??? :( 
how i convert back it into password...

Thanks
Jazib Bashir

Comment: you can use console. `User.find(id)` and then `update password`

Comment: Thanks @Tzah Mama.
It worked fine Thanks a lot.
Love u :)

Comment: How i Retrive Heroku psql db into my system and push it back.